# gcp cloud shell installing node packages gives out of space error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to run a node app using cloud shell on gcp.  I run `npm i` to install the node packages.  Towards the end this gives me the following error

```
npm ERR! npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOSPC: no space left on device, open '/home/tmp_user/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-ac519d5e/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es7.reflect.get-own-metadata-keys.js'
npm ERR! npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/tmp_user/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-ac519d5e/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/renderer/components'
npm ERR! npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOSPC: no space left on device, open '/home/tmp_user/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-ac519d5e/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_collection-to-json.js'
```

I checked the full disk usage ( on my `sudo du -sh /tmp_user)~` directory and its only 1.37 GB.  As I understand you have 5 GB of space allocated.

Comment: Not sure what `/tmp_user` is, what do you see for `df -h /home` ?

Comment: thats my user account.

Comment: Can you please share the output of `df -ih`?